# Truthiness checker function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, truthiness

I am going through this challenge on [FCC](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/everything-be-true) and I am literally half way there!

> Check if the predicate (second argument) is truthy on all elements of
>   a collection (first argument).

```
function truthCheck(collection, pre) {
  // Is everyone being true?

  for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++){
    var arr = collection[i];
    for(pre in arr){
      if (isNaN(arr[pre]) ){
        pre = false;
        return pre;
      } else if (arr[pre]){
        pre = true;
        return pre;
      }
    }
  }
}

truthCheck([{"user": "Tinky-Winky", "sex": "male"}, {"user": "Dipsy", "sex": "male"}, {"user": "Laa-Laa", "sex": "female"}, {"user": "Po", "sex": "female"}], "sex");
```

In the introduction I said I was half way there. That's because when I evaluate the truthy values first:

```
if (arr[pre]){
  pre = true;
  return pre;
}
```

all the 'truthy' tests pass.

So I suppose I should be evaluated for 'truthtiness' in a different way? I say this because my code as is gets all the 'falsey' values to pass...

Thanks all!

Comment: The truth will set you free

Comment: start by not using `isNaN` it isn't doing what you think it is. `NaN` is falsy anyway. Not to mention the fact I don't see any falsey values in your array at all...

Comment: Perhaps remove `for(pre in arr)` since `pre` is already specified as an argument to the function. It will return true for the first field, not for the given value of `pre`.

Comment: I take my statement back; that question is quite misleading, and uses the word `predicate` to mean something that it doesn't.

Comment: You're looking for `arr.every(o => o[pre])` (though "predicate" is a misnomer, it should be "property").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's false if falsey for any one of them, so test that.  Then if none of them are falsey, return true.

```
function truthCheck(collection, pre) {
    for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++){
        if (!collection[i][pre]) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
```